# Accept rate not showing anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, accept-rate

I just noticed that the accept rate of me and another user with > 5k rep is not shown anymore, although there exist enough questions (> 4 with an answer).
Why?

UPDATE:
It looks like acceptance rate for all users is missing. Example: [database structure for google plus circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411857/database-structure-for-google-plus-circles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue appears to have been resolved.